# Links breaking with double domain

Tags: config, deployment

When calling my links, they're appearing and trying to link like so:

> testurl.com/university/testurl.com/university/arizona-state/

Really it should just be

> testurl.com/university/arizona-state/

The line that is generating a category URL:

```
        <a class="university-widget w-inline-block" href="{{ category.url }}">
```

and my general.php:

```
return array(

  '*' => array(
  ),

  'localhost' => array(
    'devMode' => true,
    'siteUrl' => 'http://localhost:8888/',
    'server' => 'localhost',
        'enableCsrfProtection' => true,
        'defaultWeekStartDay' => 0,
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => 'auto',
        'defaultSearchTermOptions' => array(
            'subLeft' => true,
            'subRight' => true,
        ),
        'cpTrigger' => 'admin',

    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'baseUrl'  => 'http://localhost:8888/',
    ),
    'testToEmailAddress' => 'dev@email.com',
  ),

  'testurl.com' => array(
    'siteUrl' => 'testurl.com',
    'server' => 'localhost',

        'enableCsrfProtection' => true,
        'defaultWeekStartDay' => 0,
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => 'auto',
        'defaultSearchTermOptions' => array(
            'subLeft' => true,
            'subRight' => true,
        ),
        'cpTrigger' => 'admin',

    'environmentVariables' => array(
      'basePath' => '/var/www/html/',
      'baseUrl' => 'http://testurl.com/',
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally find this snippet to be useful

```
(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

Especially if you set up a virtual host locally in most situations you can define this in your * and it will work across local/staging/production.

Here's a basic example config:

```
'*' => [
    'environmentVariables' => [
        'basePath' => '/Users/your/path/to/site/',
        'baseUrl' => (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
    ],
    'enableCsrfProtection' => true,
    'devMode' => true,      
],

'live' => [
     'environmentVariables' => [
        'basePath' => '/srv/different/path/to/site/',
     ],
]
```

Comment: Would you be able to edit this answer and include a snippet of the config file including this line to help others.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by changing the following line:

```
'siteUrl' => 'http://testurl.com',
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your PRIMARY_SITE_URL in your .env file contains the url scheme.
Example :
PRIMARY_SITE_URL=http://test.localhost